# How to extract features of FC7 layer using Caffe, VGG16 model

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, image-recognition

Recently, I tried to use Convolutional Neural Network(CNN) to extract features of images. The model I used is VGG16, the framework is Caffe, the language chosen is Python. The problem is: I want to extract features of FC7 layer, which is 4096-d. But the features I extracted is only 1024 lines. Can anyone help me?